# How to store password in app

Tags: java, android, email

I'm using a lib to send mails in my app through my own email account. The thing is, I need to put the encrypted email in my class, and I think its too easy to reverse this and have access to my email. So, where is the best best to keep my password safe in my app? I don't have access to store nothing in a server.

The library I'm using: https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground

Comment: Try with SharedPreference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Encryption, you can look into **MessageDigest**. They provide robust hashing functionality to encrypt your passwords.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Store your password or email after hashing inside a persistent **SharedPreferences** as the other answers point out.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: you can also store these inside a SQLLite db on your android device. This will be much more efficient than sharedPreferences. Also if you make a FTS3 or FTS4 table, you can search the emails extremely quickly :) hope this helps

Comment: SharedPreferences  are not safe they can be easy pulled if phone is rooted.

Comment: Exactly why i suggested SQLLite :) Also the MessageDigest offers some pretty good hashing algos eg.. SHA 256 etc.. They are pretty difficult to crack with/without decryption techniques

Comment: As I commented in @Tapan, I was thinking of using Firebase to save the encrypted password and retrieve it when the user send email. Its a good solution?

Comment: Yea you can do that as well. That's probably the best approach anyway. do consider network latency issues though. If it takes too long to get the pass or if your internet disconnects and your request hasn't timed out, it will take a long time and users can tend to be impatient.

Comment: I see, I think i'm gonna use that and see what will happen... Thk u for the help =)

Comment: Also consider load on the server. If you intend your app to scale in the future with multitudes of people using your app, the server load can also slow things down. Personally, i would store say 3-4 passes on the phone as and when the session is alive. Also save it encrypted and in a securesharedpreference as an added measure

Comment: Hmm I can make retrive from firebase one a first email and then store the pass in the app DB... then I dont have to make user request the pass again....

Answer (score 2):

see @Kushan's answer for how to encrypt it..

You can store it inside a `SharedPreferences` safely and whenever needed you can always get it back but a good approach is to store it at servers only as **another answer's comments suggested that SharedPreferences are not safe when phone is rooted**:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("password", ""); //put when you got your password here.....
editor.commit();
```

get it back when needed by:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String password = sharedPref.getString("password", "noPass");
```

Comment: Hmmm the thing is, I still have to put my encrypted pass in the code to store using sp...I was thinking, maybe I can use firebase to store the pass and retrive only when user send the email...?

Comment: Yes a good approach i would say, but you are then internet depended so if you have to do any other function to perform with it you can't do it. But it is highly recommended not to store passwords at local device at all, Shared preferences are also risky i would say @Spotik

Comment: Well, users sending emails depends on internet, so I think thats ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117173/discussion-between-tapan-parmar-and-spotik).

Answer (score 2):

SecurePerferecne used to store password and sensitive information
here is how data stored :

```
<map>
<int name="timeout" value="500" />
<boolean name="is_logged_in" value="true" />
</map>
```

encrypted data:

```
   <map>
    <string name="TuwbBU0IrAyL9znGBJ87uEi7pW0FwYwX8SZiiKnD2VZ7">
        pD2UhS2K2MNjWm8KzpFrag==:MWm7NgaEhvaxAvA9wASUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=rroijgeWEGRDFSS/hg
    </string>
    <string name="8lqCQqn73Uo84Rj">k73tlfVNYsPshll19ztma7U">
        pD2UhS2K2MNjWm8KzpFrag==:MWm7NgaEhvaxAvA9wASUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=:jWm8KzUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=
    </string>
</map>
```

You can define a separate file for encrypted preferences.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = new SecurePreferences(context, null, "my_custom_prefs.xml");
```

store User password  :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = new SecurePreferences(context, "userpassword", "my_user_prefs.xml");
```

more [here](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)

Comment: already upvoted ur answer , its a new thing for me.but Where can i know more about SecurePreferences ? @Ra